# Produce one row in an Oracle sql query using group_by

Tags: sql, group-by, oracle10g

I'm using Oracle 10.g.  I have a table, LIB_BOOK, containing a listing of books in a library.  There are multiple copies of many of the books.  I'd like to produce a report that lists all the books with more than one copy.  I've constructed a query that lists the books, but I can't find a way to get only one row for the result.

```
Select 
    title
  , copy_number
  , isbn_10
  , category
  , book_pk
  , max(copy_number)
From LIB_BOOK
Group by 
    title
  , copy_number
  , isbn_10
  , category
  , book_pk
Order by copy_number desc
  ;
```

As you can see in the data result below, I get the results for "Conversations with God - Book 1" listed seven times.  I'd like that book to be listed only once with a "7" as the copy_number.

I took the first 32 rows of the query result, exported it to Excel and pasted the image below.

[image]

How do I construct a query to result in only one row per book, and avoid books with only one copy (copy_number > 1)?
Thanks for looking at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
  Select 
    title
  , copy_number
  , isbn_10
  , category
  , book_pk
  , copy_number
From LIB_BOOK lib
join (select title,max(copy_number) as maxcopynumber
from LIB_BOOK group by title) maxcopy on lib.title = maxcopy.title and lib.copy_number = maxcopy.maxcopynumber

Order by lib.copy_number desc
  ;
```

Comment: Hi D4TAM4X.  Thanks.  I had to add the table alias (lib) in front of the title, but then it worked fine.  The second line now reads "lib.tltle".  This query returned all the rows in the database.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove `copy_number()` and `book_pk` from the `group by`:

```
Select title, isbn_10, category,
       max(copy_number)
From LIB_BOOK
Group by title, isbn_10, category
Order by max(copy_number) desc;
```

I'm not sure what you want for `book_pk`, so I just removed it from the `select`.

Comment: Hello Gordon.  This worked.  It returned all rows in the table.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you only want to list the duplicate books, no matter what category, copy number etc. So group by book (isbn and title) and count, then remove books with less than 2 copies in your HAVING clause:

```
select 
    title
  , isbn_10
  , max(copy_number) as max_copy_number
  , count(*) as number_of_copies
from lib_book
group by title, isbn_10
having count(*) > 1
order by count(*) desc;
```

You can use the unsupported WM_CONCAT to list categories and book pks:

```
select 
    title
  , isbn_10
  , max(copy_number) as max_copy_number
  , count(*) as number_of_copies
  , wm_concat(distinct category) as categories
  , wm_concat(book_pk) as book_pks
...
```

Comment: Hello Thorsten,  Thanks for supplying me with the answer.  The first suggestion you supplied worked perfectly, and gave me ONLY the books with multiples, which is exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks again.  When I tried the wm_contact in SQL Developer 4.0 I got the error message: ORA-00904: "WM_CONCAT": invalid identifier.  Again, the first worked perfectly.  Thanks again!

Comment: Okay. So that's the first time I see an Oracle 10g without that function. Oracle always warned us that this function was unsupported, but they delivered it with their DBMS throughout the years. I suppose hence that a DBA removed it purposely from your version.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you are getting getting multiple rows because some of the fields which you are grouping by are different for the same book like copy number and book pk ...

Please try the below query:

SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT TITLE,
               COPY_NUMBER,
               ISBN_10,
               CATEGORY,
               BOOK_PK,
               COPY_NUMBER,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ISBN ORDER BY COPY_NUMBER DESC) RN
          FROM LIB_BOOK) X
 WHERE RN = 1

Comment: Hi Marz,  I tried this.  I had to change the ISBN to ISBN_10 in the PARTITION BY clause, which was simple enough to fix.  When I tried again with that change I got the error: ORA-30484: missing window specification for this function.  It was pointing to the ROW_NUMBER() in the inner Select statement.

Comment: Please try this one: SELECT * FROM (SELECT TITLE, COPY_NUMBER, ISBN_10, CATEGORY, BOOK_PK,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ISBN_10 ORDER BY COPY_NUMBER DESC) RN FROM LIB_BOOK) X 
 WHERE RN = 1

Comment: Hi Marz.  Thanks.  If I add "And copy_number > 1
  Order By copy_number desc;" to the query you gave, it produces exactly what I need.  Thanks again for all your help.